# How to submit multiple dropdown lists as well as other parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUsgK.png) <- each color line represents that every change affects the week for student underlined with the same color.

I have two students, for which I am trying to create an attendance sheet. Each student is enrolled in a class that can be either 1 week, 10 weeks or 14 weeks. Moreover, each dropdown for each student has an option of "Present", "Absent", or "Out" - in where it assumes that every student is present at first.

The problem arises when I try to save this information to the database. I have an attendance table with the rows of "enrollment_id" <- represents every student enrolled in a class, "week", and "status." Furthermore, I am able to retrieve the value of the 20 dropdown boxes in an array of: "'Present', 'Present', 'Absent', 'Out,' and so on...

I am able to retrieve the id for a class, since that is what first pops-up for you to know which students are enrolled in them. I cannot retrieve the week for the attendance changed and the enrollment id for the student. I am running a (1..x) loop in order to display every week title and every week dropdown box.

This my attendance show.html.erb:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; border: solid pink 3px;">
  <%= form_for @attendance do |a| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> Students </th>
            <% Enrollment.where(klass_id: @klass.id).count('id') do |x| %>
                <% (1..x.klass.duration_weeks).each do |y| %>
                    <th> <%= "Week " %><%= y %> </th>
                <% end %> 
            </tr>
            <% @enrollment.each do |e| %>
            <tr>
                <td> <%= e.student.first_name + " " + e.student.last_name %> </td>
                    <%(1..x.klass.duration_weeks).each do |f| %>
                        <td> <%= select_tag 'status[]', options_for_select(@status) %> </td>    
                            <%= hidden_field_tag 'current_klass', @klass.model  %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag 'week', f %>
                            <%= hidden_field_tag 'student', e.id %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
    <%= a.submit "Turn list in"%>
<% end %>
```

And this is my attendances_controller.erb:

```
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController

  #respond_to :html, :js

  require 'pry'

  def index
    @klass = Klass.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def show

    @enrollment = Enrollment.all
    @student = Student.all
    @klass = Klass.find(params[:id])
    @attendance = Attendance.new
    @status = {'Present' => 'Present', 'Out' => 'Out', 'Absent' => 'Absent'}

    #binding.pry
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

 def create

   binding.pry
   puts params[:current_klass]
   puts params[:status]


   #@att = Attendance.new
   #@att.enrollment_id = e.id 
   #@att.week = f
   #@att.status = "Absent"
   #@att.save
  end
end
```

> Started POST "/attendances" for ::1 at 2018-07-19 11:22:18 -0400 
>   Processing by AttendancesController#create as HTML  Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"NEwNcWmS9axhLhlTJt/9W04+V3mCJREqaQqXti7f07RppbYqz8/6nE2O
>   0EYcesyBQ1/L97uJne/hvdyADjdBJg==",
>   "attendance"=>{"status"=>"Present"}, "current_klass"=>"I_K101",
>   "week"=>"10", "student"=>"2", "commit"=>"Turn list in"}

This is the information I get from my console once I click on the submit button. Note it only shows the last week and shows the id for the last student. I can display the attendances, because I changed my code.

Thanks a lot for any help in advance.

Comment: What are the fields in Attendance?  Are you planning to save all the records for a given student in a given class in a single record?  Or all the students for a given class in a single record?  Or does each student have a correlating attendance record for a given class for a given week?

Comment: The fields for attendance are enrollment_id, week, and status. I want to save those three values to the attendance table. I am planning to save these for every "week" that a student is marked as present, absent, or out. The attendance table should look something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/tcwBn1D)

Comment: hmm.. this is more of a job for form_tag.  I'll show you an example, few minutes.